# WPF listview items fires unlimited MouseEnter and MouseLeave events

Tags: c#, wpf

I have list view with some items in it, an image with title and description. 
I have to implement a functionality to show an hover with an image when user **mouseenter** in the area of image with in the list item.

Ever thing is working fine but have one problem.
Every time when i hover over any image, hovered image causing blinking underneath there will be unlimited calls of **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** events.

I did googling and find [SCOTT HANSELMAN's blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MouseEnterAndMouseLeaveLoopsInWPF.aspx) but nothing works for me.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentSlideItems}" Name="listSlides" SelectionChanged="listSlides_SelectionChanged" KeyDown="listSlides_KeyDown" Padding="0" SelectionMode="Multiple" PreviewMouseDoubleClick="listSlides_PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,ElementName=listSlides}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Margin="0,2">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" MaxWidth="150" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0" MouseEnter="image1_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="image1_MouseLeave">
                            </Image>
                        </Border>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Margin="5,4,2,2" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" Margin="5,2,2,2" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxHeight="80" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**Edit:** with events

```
 private void image1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var srcImg = e.Source as System.Windows.Controls.Image;
        showPopup(srcImg);

    }

    private void image1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var pop = (Popup)this.FindResource("popup");

        if (!pop.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            if (!popupFlag)
            {
                pop.IsOpen = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the mouseEnter and mouseLeave from image and adding it to border? Also, are you modifying the image in any of the events?

Comment: @Prajwal yes, not working.

Comment: Can you post both events as well? looks like you are modifying the image in someway.

Comment: sure, in edit @Prajwal

Comment: I believe the issue is in `Popup`. In `image1_MouseEnter` you're showing a pop-up and in `image1_MouseLeave` you are hiding it. This is causing a loop.

Comment: But that is what i am trying to do, when user hover over my image it will be popped out and when user leaves the popup will be hide. (please read the question again)

Comment: Be aware that when you show the popup on top of the Image control (so that it's under the cursor), the Image immediately gets a MouseLeave event. Your approach won't work this way. Probably close the popup when itself gets a MouseLeave event.

Comment: @Clemens that is the best suggested (Y) Thank you.

Comment: @Clemens can you post this as an answer for others to learn. Thank you